# What is the timestamp returned by tf2 lookup_transform in ros noetic

Tags: ros, robotics, coordinate-transformation

Consider I have 3 co-ordinate systems eg: **A, B and X**

I am currently try to do **lookup_transform** between two frames eg: Source as A and Destination as B.

In **/tf** topic I have the transforms of **A -> X** and **X ->B**. I wanted to know what timestamp does the lookup_transform provide for the resultant transformation when I do a transformation from **A -> B**

For example:

If **A -> X** timestamp is **T** ns and **X -> B** timestamp is **T + 1** ns, what will be the resultant timestamp of transform **A -> B**

When I did some tests, I found that the resultant timestamp for **A -> B** is either of  **A -> X** or **X -> B** , But I do not know how lookup_transform decides upon the timestamps for the result.

For my use case I always want to have the timestamp of **A -> X** in the resultant value

I use the tf function for lookup of latest transfórm (Time(0))
[Lookup_Transform function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyXDY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tf2 saves your transformations in a graph updating the edges of this graph whenever the  `tf_listener` receives a new message from the `tf_broadcaster`. When queried, the listener performs interpolation between the nearest values since you are using Time(0) it will be the latest 2 values. And for the time stamps it will return the latest common time across the queried values.
So in your example the time will be the latest common time A -> X and X -> B existed.
For more information you can read [this paper](http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=TePRA2013_Foote.pdf)